# Sum of array in a different way

Tags: arrays, sum, zigzag

Let assume I have an MxN array and I should sum this array like in image as shown below;

[Array sum](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cto9S.png)

I should sum all x's , all y's , all z's and all g's. I need an approach. My_Brain.exe has stopped and I couldn't find any approach to solve this problem.

Comment: Ok, take a break. Take a walk, read a book, take a nap, have sex, do something else. Then come back to the problem and come up with an approach. _THEN_ come back here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SumColumnZigZag(column) {
    Sum = 0
    for row = 0; row < rows; row++ {
        sum += array[row][column + (row % 2)*(1 - 2*(column % 2))]
    }
    return sum
}
```

% is the modulo operator